# Stock images for Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

does anybody know how I can access the stock Xcode images? For example, I really want to be able to use the original back button image like in this picture :)[image]

Comment: Can't you just create a button image like that one and put it on your button ?

Comment: That would require a lot of work as I wanna be able to use a lot of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the official apple images. Even if you could they are copyright of Apple Inc and could pose a problem when you are trying to get the app approved.

If you are using a navigation controller, you can remove the standard text "Back" to get just the icon you seem to be after by adding the following to the following to the viewController **BEFORE** the one you wish the back button to appear on.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"";
```

For icons in general the [Glyphish icon pack](http://www.glyphish.com/) is very comprehensive, even the free version (which does require attribution) is usually enough!

Comment: Oh okay, I thought they would provide them as part of the resources of Xcode but I guess not. Thanks! :)

Comment: I agree! It would allow developers to create the 'consistent interface' apple is after.

Comment: Sorry! It told me I needed to wait more time when I did and it slipped my mind. Done now :)